# Polygon contains point algorithm explanation

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry

I have seen variants of this solution on many different SO questions about polygons containing a point, but the issue is none of the authors give any explanation.  I cannot seem to figure out how this function works, and seeing that many other commenters have had their questions about this go unanswered, I thought it best to just ask so there would be a concrete explanation.

Also, are there any cases where this function fails?

**UPDATE:**
I do know how the raycasting method works, there are some very good resources for that, but I am really confused how this code works specifically.

```
public static bool(ean) PolygonContainsPoint(Point[] polygon, Point point)
{
    bool(ean) result = false;
    int j = polygon.Count - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < polygon.Count; i++)
    {
        if (polygon[i].Y < point.Y && polygon[j].Y >= point.Y || polygon[j].Y < point.Y && polygon[i].Y >= point.Y)
        {
            if (polygon[i].X + (point.Y - polygon[i].Y) / (polygon[j].Y - polygon[i].Y) * (polygon[j].X - polygon[i].X) < point.X)
            {
                result = !result;
            }
        }
        j = i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Don't tag spam. `var result`? What language is this?

Comment: I wrote this in C#, but I have seen this function in Java and C++ on this site as well.  I edited the code so it is more language agnostic.

Comment: We need the type of what a polygon is and what its members mean and what "contains" means and what you want to do on edge cases.  What invarients are held.  I'd guess you are doing a raycast along the x axis to negative infinity, and counitng how many segments it hits; if osd, inside, if even, outside?  You'll get some infinitesimal glitches based on rounding issues if so, but nothing of significant volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the [ray casting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm) described on Wikipedia.

> [image: RecursiveEvenPolygon]
>
> The number of intersections for a ray passing from the exterior of the polygon to any point; if odd, it shows that the point lies inside the polygon. If it is even, the point lies outside the polygon; this test also works in three dimensions.

---

```cs
int j = polygon.Count - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < polygon.Count; i++)
{
    // ...
    j = i;
}
```

*Explanation:* The code loops through each line segment of the polygon, with `i` being index of current point, and `j` being index of previous point (previous of first point is the last point, since polygon is closed).

---

```cs
if (polygon[i].Y < point.Y && polygon[j].Y >= point.Y ||
    polygon[j].Y < point.Y && polygon[i].Y >= point.Y)
```

*Explanation:* If the polygon line segment crosses line **`O`**, i.e. if it starts above and ends below, *or* starts below and ends above.

---

```cs
if (polygon[i].X + (point.Y - polygon[i].Y)
    / (polygon[j].Y - polygon[i].Y)
    * (polygon[j].X - polygon[i].X)
    < point.X)
```

*Explanation:* Calculate the X coordinate where the polygon line segment crosses line **`O`**, then test if that is to the left of target point.

---

```cs
result = false;
for each segment:
    if segment crosses on the left:
        result = !result;
return result;
```

*Explanation:* If the number of polygon line segments crossing line **`O`** to the left of the target point is *odd*, then the target point is inside the polygon.